# Trigger lightbox with button onclick

Tags: lightbox

I am using lightbox by Lokesh Dhakar for an image gallery. I want to be able to initiate the lightbox gallery by clicking a button.

```
 <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick='parent.$.lightbox({href:".gallery"}); return false;'><img style="margin-left:60px;" src="/images/template/assets/view.png" alt="View Gallery" width="120" height="33" /> </span>
```

Something along these lines...but this does not work for me.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is anything happening at all?

Comment: nothing is happening